# How to change date calender format in android Datepicker?

Tags: android, date, datepicker

I want to show date format 01-01-2014 while selecting date from android date picker
but i get in format 1-1-2014 due to this i get problem while searching date

here is my code

```
// On click Of Button
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {        
    case R.id.btnAESubmit:
        saveData();
        break;
    case R.id.lblAEDate:
        showDialog(AE_DT_DIALOG_ID);
        break;
    }
}

// to create Date dialog
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case AE_DT_DIALOG_ID:
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // set date picker as current date
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, yy, mm, dd);
    }
    return null;
}

// DAte Listener Call on date dialog call
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;          
        day = selectedDay;
        StringBuilder Date;         
        Date = new StringBuilder().append(day).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(year).append(" ");

        // set selected date into lbl View
        lblAEDate.setText(Date);
    }
};
```

how to format selected date in to this way 01-01-2014?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String formattedDay = (String.valueOf(day));
String formattedMonth = (String.valueOf(month));

if(day < 10)
{
    formattedDay = "0" + day;
}

if(month< 10)
{
    formattedMonth = "0" + Month;
}
```

put this code right before `StringBuilder Date;` and remove  `year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;

        day = selectedDay;`

Then pass `formattedDay`, `formattedMonth` and `year` to your StringBuilder.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: is it proper way ..? as i am also doing same thing in if condition

Comment: It worked for me.. You tested it? In what if condition are you doing the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
    populateSetDate(yy, mm + 1, dd);
}

public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    String formattedDay = (String.valueOf(day));
    String formattedMonth = (String.valueOf(month));

    if (day < 10) {
        formattedDay = "0" + day;
    }

    if (month < 10) {
        formattedMonth = "0" + month;
    }

    btnDate.setText(formattedDay + "-" + formattedMonth + "-" + year);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here i got alternative for accepted answer

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {          
        String dt;
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth + 1;
        day = selectedDay;
        try {
            dt = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); // Set your date format
            Date currentDt = null;          
            currentDt = sdf.parse(dt);
            String d = sdf.format(currentDt);
            // set selected date into lbl View
            lblDate.setText(d);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you can set the dateformat to whatever you want, check the [SimpleDateFormat JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for examples.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String test = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
Log.e("TEST", test);
```